OkHttp3 Request.Builder's post function won't accept FormBody as argument
Using OkHttp3 4.12.0 in Android Studio (2023.2.1 Patch 1) with Kotlin, I'm attempting to post a FormBody but the post function from Request.Builder() won't accept FormBody as an argument since it requires a RequestBody, even though the former extends the latter.
Even trying to use the example straight out of their documentation provides the same issue:
val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
    .add("search", "Jurassic Park")
    .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
     .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php")
     .post(formBody)
     .build()

Type mismatch.
Required:
    RequestBody!
Found:
    FormBody

I can add as RequestBody to the end of the formBody definition which removes the warning from post but creates another that warns that this cast can never succeed
What am I missing, and what's the proper way to post a form body here?

Please also share your import statements. You probably imported the wrong Request class. The code looks fine as it is.

Absolutely right, looks like there were some in there from com.squareup.okhttp still in there. If you'd like to submit answer I'll happily mark it as accepted!

The code looks fine, you probably have just the wrong Request class imported. It should be this:
import okhttp3.Request

